# Cloud masking and SLC error correction using GEE

Tags: cloud, google-earth-engine, landsat

I have downloaded a few images from USGS earth explorer. I can see cloud cover, cloud shadow and SLC errors in those images. I have uploaded raster images as an asset (Tiff format) into Google Earth Engine (GEE).

How to perform cloud masking and SLC error correction in GEE on assets (image)?